# Function does not return expected value, when max value returns NULL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, null, case, coalesce

I have created function to return the max number from  data set, which works fine, if the data set exists ie., if MAX returns a VALUE.

If there is no matching data set I need to return a value of 0, but no matter what I try the retrieval either equals no value or I get the no data found.

Have tried when `when no data found`, `when others` and `null values` as below but cant get this function to return 0 if max value is not found ie., if MAX value returns `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_msm
    (in_site_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id%TYPE
    ,in_zone_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id%TYPE
    ,in_mod AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module%TYPE)

RETURN NUMBER
IS

v_msm NUMBER;
NULL_VALUES EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight)
    INTO v_msm
    FROM AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS 
    WHERE AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id = in_site_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id = in_zone_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE in_mod||'%'; 

RETURN (v_msm);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NULL_VALUES
    THEN
    RETURN 0;

END sitezone_msm;
```

Have spent an age playing with this but cant get desired results and suggestions much appreciated

Comment: You can try `SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight) IS NULL THEN  0 ELSE MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this NVL function is generally used for handling NULL values

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_msm
    (in_site_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id%TYPE
    ,in_zone_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id%TYPE
    ,in_mod AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module%TYPE)

RETURN NUMBER
IS

v_msm NUMBER;
--NULL_VALUES EXCEPTION; -- not required

BEGIN
    SELECT nvl(MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight),0)
    INTO v_msm
    FROM AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS 
    WHERE AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id = in_site_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id = in_zone_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE in_mod||'%'; 

RETURN (v_msm);

EXCEPTION  
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
    RETURN 0;

END sitezone_msm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OPC_OP.sitezone_msm
    (in_site_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id%TYPE
    ,in_zone_id AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id%TYPE
    ,in_mod AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module%TYPE)

RETURN NUMBER
IS

v_msm NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.weight),0)
    INTO v_msm
    FROM AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS 
    WHERE AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.site_id = in_site_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.zone_id = in_zone_id
    AND AW_ACTIVE_ALARMS.module LIKE in_mod||'%'; 

RETURN (v_msm);

END sitezone_msm;
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, that does the trick.  I'm guessing that the select max does not raise an exception even if the where clause finds no match ?

Comment: That's right, aggregate functions (without a GROUP BY) never raise NO_DATA_FOUND exceptions